# C# SSIS Script Task - Add Thousand Seperator when formatting Excel column

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, etl, script-task

Currently using the following C# in a script task in SSIS to format an Excel column as a Number.

```
sheet.Columns[6].NumberFormat = "0.00";
```

However when the column is created the thousands separator is missing. Is there a way to add this in?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use this:

`sheet.Columns[6].NumberFormat = "#,##0.00";`

Places with zeros will show even if the value is 0, whereas places with pound signs (#) will only show if needed.

The following are some examples of what will show when using this format:

```
10000 -> 10,000.00
 1000 -> 1,000.00
   10 -> 10.00
 5.25 -> 5.25
  .25 -> 0.25
   .1 -> 0.10
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried this and it doesn't work i'm afraid, there is no thousands seperator present

Comment: @OllieSP Interesting. Perhaps could you update your question to have more of the code involved? It may be affected by how the data is populated in the column

Comment: This works but the problem is, the column is then not formatted as number but its formatted as custom. Also if you have a value like this: 100.00 the thousand separator will apprear like this:  ,100.00

Comment: @Leon When I use this number format in Excel, the value 100.00 shows as "100.00", not ",100.00". What scenario results in the leading comma?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, here is what I found:

Looking here, I found a solution that should work for you: [format a number with commas and decimals in C# (asp.net MVC3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035506/format-a-number-with-commas-and-decimals-in-c-sharp-asp-net-mvc3/31569800)

To summarize the post, it states you should define a variable (number) and then initialize it. After, you will format twice:  First using `.ToDecimal(number)` then `.ToString(("#,##0.00")`

Now, let's apply this to your example:

Define & initialize your variable -- let's say you call it the name of the 6th column in your sheet (for this example, let's assume you define it as constant that never changes named 'cost')

```cs
public const int cost = sheet.Columns[6]
```

Then you want to format:

```cs
Convert.ToDecimal(cost).ToString("#,##0.00");
```

This SHOULD get you the desired result.

Comment: It could be beneficial to use [markdown formatting for your code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links)

Comment: Thank you, mykhailo.romaniuk! New here, but want to help out however possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Number Format expression consists of the following numeric specifiers:

> **#** : *Digit placeholder* 
>   **0** : *Zero placeholder* 
>   **,** : *Decimal point* 
>   **.** : *Decimal separator* 
>   **[Red]** : *Color specifier* 
>   **%** : *Percentage placeholder*

You can use the following expression to show the thousands separators:

```
sheet.Columns[6].NumberFormat = "#,##0.00";
```

**Examples** *(image taken from references below)*:

[image]

#### References:

- [Range.NumberFormat property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat)
- [How to Set Number Format in Excel using Spire.XLS in C#, VB.NET](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Cells/How-to-Set-Number-Format-in-Excel-using-Spire.XLS-in-C-VB.NET.html)
- [Excel number format](https://www.iditect.com/faq/excel/number-format.html)

Comment: Hi, i've tried this and it doesn't work i'm afraid, there is no thousands seperator present

Comment: @OllieSP can you provide the whole code you are implementing, since it may be other lines of codes that change the column behavior.